# undefined reference to `gzopen' in moses

Tags: c++, gcc, moses

I'm currently trying to install moses script, part of moses the machine translation tool, but keep getting error:

```
/home/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering/reordering_classes.cpp:349: undefined reference to `gzopen'
/home/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering/reordering_classes.cpp:353: undefined reference to `gzwrite'
/home/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering/reordering_classes.cpp:356: undefined reference to `gzclose'
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.1 in Ubuntu 11.10, and already installed the zlib1g-dev package. The moses source is the latest (2010-08-13).

What should I do? Do I need to install some additional package?

Comment: yes, this is the command used to compile and link reordering_classes.cpp:

g++ -O6 -g -c reordering_classes.cpp
g++ -lz score.cpp reordering_classes.o -o score

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `-lz` after  your files:

```
g++ score.cpp reordering_classes.o -lz -o score
```

Comment: Thank you very much! after changing the order in the Makefile, the compile now works! thx :D